# Zeppelin restart interpreter after authentication using REST api

Tags: rest, curl, apache-zeppelin

I am managing a zeppelin server and I am trying to restart the zeppelin interpreter using REST api call. I have turned authentication on. Hence I'm trying to first get the sessionID usin login api and then pass it to the next PUT request to restart the interpreter.

Here are the steps I'm following.

Getting Session ID:

```
curl -i --data 'userName=admin&password=admin123' -X POST http://zeppelin-server.com:8055/api/login
```

Response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Date: Tue, 08 Aug 2017 15:09:14 GMT
 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Content-Type
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD, DELETE
 Date: Tuesday, August 8, 2017 11:09:14 AM EDT
 Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Mon, 07-Aug-2017 15:09:14 GMT
 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=438b05e7-1a9a-4cbe-aa06-1c3dfv454976; Path=/; HttpOnly
 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Mon, 07-Aug-2017 15:09:14 GMT
 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=f404ad12-a21b-4c6c-bcde-d4f8b59c076a; Path=/; HttpOnly
 Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Mon, 07-Aug-2017 15:09:14 GMT
 Content-Type: application/json
 Date: Tue, 08 Aug 2017 15:09:14 GMT
 Content-Length: 123
 Server: Jetty(9.2.15.v20160210)

 {"status":"OK","message":"","body":{"principal":"admin","ticket":"f329g1cc-d488-4aef-9b89-6b206ee71496","roles":"[admin]"}}
```

Next, I'm passing the JSESSIONID to the PUT request for restarting the interpreter

```
 curl -v -i -b 'JSESSIONID=438b05e7-1a9a-4cbe-aa06-1c3dfv454976; Path=/; HttpOnly' -X PUT http://zeppelin-server.com:8055/api/interpreter/setting/restart/2CGBW7NIF
```

Response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

I'm not getting the json response status which I'm otherwise getting when I turn the authentication off.

Could anyone point out what am I doing wrong here. I was following the instructions here.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/52840/authentication-with-the-zeppelin-rest-api.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey the reason why you get the 302 Found Code  is because you have just provided the half Cookie. In your example the curl sould be:

```
 curl -v -i -b 'JSESSIONID=f404ad12-a21b-4c6c-bcde-d4f8b59c076a; Path=/; HttpOnly; rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Mon, 07-Aug-2017 15:09:14 GMT' -X PUT http://zeppelin-server.com:8055/api/interpreter/setting/restart/2CGBW7NIF
```

That worked for me. Hope this will help you too!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using -c parameter (to store the cookie) and -b (to recover and send).

Please find attached my example code:

```
#Get credentials
curl  --data 'userName=user1&password=user1' -c cookies.txt -XPOST http://$IP:8080/api/login
...
#Use credential to get list of notebooks
curl -b cookies.txt -XGET http://<server>:8080/api/notebook
```

I hope this helps you.

Regards!